# Directly file in camel route without file consumer

Tags: apache-camel

Is there a way to have camel delete a file, that did not come from the file consumer?

To be more exact: in my route I collect a list of files (not from the file component), which I then process. After that, I want to delete them all.

Of course I could just make a processor, that uses e.g. Apache FileUtils, but I wonder, if there is a way to have camel handle it.

Using the split expression I could have each file processed separately, so having a process, that just deletes a single file would be fine.

Greets
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you would need to write some code yourself that deletes the file(s) you want. You can then add that as an onCompletion or call a bean/processor at the end of your route. Or add a custom route policy and attach it to the route etc. There are more ways to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I created a processor now, that deletes the file: **.process(exchange -> Files.delete(exchange.getIn().getBody(Path.class)))** But this feels very "manual", as always when I write manual code in a route. But I guess its the correct way..